# Thinking Sphinx- query to check for any of array x or none of array y

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I've got an employee search feature that is used by managers to search for employees.  It needs to return employees who are assigned to any of the same markets that the manager (the user) is assigned to, as well as employees who have not yet been assigned to any markets.

For example:

```
Employee      Assigned market ids
manager_1:      [1, 2]
employee_1:     [1, 3]
employee_2:     [3, 4]
employee_3:     []
```

A search done by manager_1 should return employee_1 and employee_3.

The code that builds the query:

```
def populate_search_results(query, market_ids)

  user_assigned_market_ids = market_ids.join('|')
  all_market_ids = Market.all.map(&:id).join(',')

  if params[:status] == 'current'
    is_current = 1
  else
    is_current = 0
  end

  full_query = "#{query} @assigned_market_ids (#{user_assigned_market_ids} | -(#{all_assigned_market_ids})) @current #{is_current})"

  @employees = Employee.search(full_query, :match_mode => :extended).page(params[:page]).per(25)
end
```

A simple version of the query- `full_query = "#{query} @assigned_market_ids !(#{all_assigned_market_ids})"` works, and returns employees who aren't assigned to any markets, but I can't get it to work with both `user_assigned_market_ids` and `all_assigned_market_ids` in the same query.

I've tried several different syntax combinations, but the results range from returning the wrong employees, to Sphinx syntax errors, to just returning 0 results.

If someone who understands building Sphinx queries could point out what I'm doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.